# Where to download Windows SDK for Windows XP now that Microsoft is no longer supporting it?

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-xp

Even the archive doesn't go back far enough.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ff851942.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It says for example "Windows SDK **for Windows 7** and .NET Framework 4", but if you look at the description:

> Released in June 2010, this SDK provides Windows 7 headers, libraries,
>   documentation, samples, and **tools to develop applications for** Windows
>   7, **Windows XP**, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server
>   2008, and .NET Framework versions 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 SP1, and 4.0.

Answer (score 6):

*Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4* is the latest SDK that support **Windows XP** target.

- [Official download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442)
- [Official links to other SDK versions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK for more info.